# Collision in Unity3d in an intervall?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I have a question on the following method

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D ext_coll)
{
      // Do something
}
```

This method works perefectly except in one case. Lets say i want to check constantly, like every 10 ms or something if i am on the ground, means if i collide. The collider-method runs only one time! Means when i am colliding against something it runs on time and thats it. What i want to have is something that checks constantly if i am colliding, something like this:

```
10MS -> NOT COLLIDING
20MS -> NOT COLLIDING
30MS -> NOT COLLIDING
40MS -> NOT COLLIDING
50MS -> COLLIDING
60MS -> COLLIDING
70MS -> COLLIDING
80MS -> NOT COLLIDING
90MS -> NOT COLLIDING
```

I really would need to check consantly. Does anyone have a good solution to that?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods that i can think of: [OnCollisionStay](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html) and [Physics.CheckSphere](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html)

**OnCollisionStay**

---

> OnCollisionStay is called once per frame for every collider/rigidbody that is touching rigidbody/collider.

In your case you could do something similar to the following:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnCollisionStay() {

            // Do Something

    }
}
```

**Physics.CheckSphere**

---

[Physics.CheckSphere](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html) returns **true** if there are any colliders within the sphere. (If you need the list of colliders, use [Physics.OverlapSphere](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html)).

The code below will check if there is any collider within a defined sphere every frame (whenever update is called).

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float sphereRadius;
    void Update() {
        if (Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, sphereRadius))

           //Do something

        }
    }
```

*(If you want to define your own intervals instead of every frame you can place the code within a co-routine for either method).*